# Changing column headers after plotting table using Qt4

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a piece of code that produces a table and allow you to input data as required. The table is shown below:

[image]

What is actually being inputted into the table is not always temperature and voltage and rather than each time I run through the code having to go and change the column headers, it would be nice if I could do it after the table is plotted by clicking on it.

I thought this might be done automatically as I can click on the table and change the values even after using the 'insert into table' button.

So my question is, how do I change the column headers by clicking on them?

My code is below:

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.setRowCount(0)
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.textInput1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.textInput2 = QtGui.QLineEdit()

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Insert into table")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.populateTable)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.textInput1)
        layout.addWidget(self.textInput2)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(("Temperatures;Voltages").split(";"))


    def populateTable(self):

        text1 = self.textInput1.text()
        text2 = self.textInput2.text()

        row = self.table.rowCount()
        self.table.insertRow(row)
        self.table.setItem(row, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(text1))
        self.table.setItem(row, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(text2))

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.setGeometry(400, 100, 550, 450)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could connect the header's `sectionDoubleClicked` and rename the relevant header using `setText`.

connect the header's sectionDoubleClicked to a function:

```
self.table.horizontalHeader().sectionDoubleClicked.connect(self.renameHeader)
```

get user-input for a new title and rename:

```
def renameHeader(self, index):
    oldHeader = self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(index).text()
    newHeader, confirm = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self,
                                                   'Rename Header',
                                                   '',
                                                   QtGui.QLineEdit.Normal,
                                                   oldHeader)
    if confirm:
        self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(index).setText(newHeader)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'index'?

Comment: Once you connect `sectionDoubleClicked`  to a function, one of the function's arguments is `index` which indicates the position (column) of the clicked header -- in your case it'll be either 0 or 1.

Just to clarify, the function is called as you double click on a header; you don't have to worry about explicitly passing `index` as an argument.

Comment: Ah yes. I had just put `self.table.horizontalHeader().sectionDoubleClicked.connect(self.renameHeader)` in the wrong place which was giving me the issues I think. I have moved things around now and it works for me, thanks for the help.